# Why do i keep getting break error? I have the same problem with continue and pass

Tags: python, automation, break, auto, webbot

```
from webbot import Browser
import time
import pyautogui
from pyautogui import *
web = Browser()
a == True
web.go_to('http://au.yahoo.com//')
web.scrolly(100)
if a == True:
    try:
        web.click('Skip for now')
        break
web.click('Mail')
time.sleep(10)
pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
```

break keeps coming up with unexpected error

I want it to try click 'skip for now', if not then continue the code

Comment: Look up how to properly use `try`.  (Hint: what should the program do if the code in the `try` fails?)

Comment: break is meant to break free of a loop. As there is no loop here break doesn't work and so brings error. If you want your program to continue just don't put a break. And when you call for a try you should mention exception so as mentioned below write at least except : pass

Comment: @Apo but then it comes up with an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    web.click("Skip for now")
except:
    pass
```

Comment: when i run it an error comes up saying break is outside loop

Comment: forget the break !

Answer (score -1):

```
web = Browser()
a == True
web.go_to('http://au.yahoo.com//')
web.scrolly(100)
if a == True:
    try:
        web.click('Skip for now')
    except:
        pass
web.click('Mail')
time.sleep(10)
pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
```

EDIT : miss spell of except